# Good programming practice to assign direct values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

**Edit:**
Added JSfiddle to better demonstrate

So I am not sure if this is good programming, but I have a table with multiple cells and some of them are dependent on others (>, <, etc.) I also have a form where the values are dependent on others also.

I am using an XSLT to generate these table/form dynamically from an XML.So depending on the XML the page will look different and have different data. The problem is should I design the XML such that it has a reference to the individual element that it depends on? Such that when I enter a value I will check if the value enters meets the condition for the dependency. In this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3yZF/2/)** the cell have a data-valueLimits that explicitly tell which cell it needs to check

```
<tbody><tr class="tableRow">
<td ><input type="Text" id="1102" style="text-align:center;" data-valuelimits="&   
lt;=:1103"/></td>
<td><input type="Text" id="1103" style="text-align:center;" data-valuelimits="&  
gt;=:1102"/></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I feel this is a bit hackish because I am explicitly telling which element it needs to check.

I was hoping for something more dynamic where if I can click any element and have just look in a place.

Example, if I unfocus the cell in column 1 row 1, I fire an event that looks up then information in the column's header that says this column is less than column 2. So I then get the cell in column 2 row 1 to check if the value in the cell in column 1 row 1 is less than the cell in column 2 row 1. The problem with this though is that they have to be grouped together while the element can be anywhere. In this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKBjX/2/)** the data-valueLimits are in the header and I will have to programmaticly get the information determine which column base on that information and which row the cell unfocus is at to get the value to comapre. This way I do not need to know what cell it is, but the location.

```
<thead><tr>
<th ><label data-valuelimits="&lt;=:MaxNum" name="MinNum">Min Number</label></th>
<th class="dataTableHeader"><label data-valuelimits="&gt;=:MinNum" name="MaxNum">Max   
Number</label></th>
</tr></thead>
```

Do anybody know a way to combine both ways?

Comment: I doubt many people would read through that block of text, and then of those that do, it really isn't very clear. In the end though, you appear to be asking for an opinion (*"should I design the XML such that it has a reference to the individual element that it depends on?"*) which is off topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: 1000 words, 0 codes.. You could show us your code or some part of it and its far better then explaining the structure of your program.

Comment: @VuralAcar KevinB I see your point I added code to better demostrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a custom checksum validation is quite simple actually. You could probably build upon an existing framework such as [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) however I wanted to keep all this simple.

You could use a `data-checksum` attribute on elements that requires a checksum and use event delegation to capture every `blur` events of all `input[type="text"]` elements that have this attribute. In my example a checksum of `inputA + inputB` means that the value needs to equal the sum of the fields named `inputA` and `inputB` respectively.

*Note: blur doesn't bubble up in some browsers, so you might not be able to use event delegation. It could be safer to add event listeners to all elements.*

E.g.

HTML

```
<input name="inputA" type="text">
<input name="inputB" type="text">
<input name="inputC" type="text" data-checksum="inputA + inputB">
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    var spacesRx = /\s/g,
        wordBoundaryRx = /\b/,
        operatorsRx = /[+\-*\\]/;

    $(document).on('blur', 'input[type=text][data-checksum]', function (e) {
        var $this = $(e.currentTarget),

            //default operator
            operator = '+',

            //naive parsing of the checksum expression
            parts = $this.data('checksum').replace(spacesRx, '').split(wordBoundaryRx),

            //calculate the result of the checksum expression
            result = parts.reduce(function (res, item) {
                if (operatorsRx.test(item)) {
                    operator = item;
                    return res;
                }

                //evil eval to shorten code example
                return eval('res' + operator + '=' + ($('input[type=text][name="' + item + '"]').val() || 0));

            }, 0);

        if (result !== parseInt($this.val(), 10)) {
            console.warn('error, expecting ' + result + ' for field ' + $this.prop('name'));
        }
    });
});
```

*Note: Please also note that the validation config doesn't have to be stored in the markup.*

EDIT:

> yeah this is what I had in mind, but I feel that it is very hackish since I am in a sense "hard coding" things, such as explicitly telling
>   it inputA and inputB. But if this is the only way I guess.

Well if there isin't any algorithm you can use to determine the rules based on the sole knowledge of which element is being validated, there's no other way than specifying the rules. **Unless you are Chuck Norris...**

Comment: yeah this is what I had in mind, but I feel that it is very hackish since I am in a sense "hard coding" things, such as explicitly telling it inputA and inputB. But if this is the only way I guess.

Comment: Did you mean `|| 0` or `| 0`?  As is, nothing prevents the `+` operator from doing string concatenation.

Comment: @JackThor, Well how would you like to determine these otherwise? Do you have an algorithm that can be used, like two fields below the current field or something similar? If you do not there's no other way than specifying the rules.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Well that's just a simple example, I have assumed that only numbers could be entered within the fields or that they could be blank. I meant `|| 0` so that `''` would yield `0`.